Kotlin code throws error during dagger initialization
On first code snippet, i'm getting dagger initialization exception on runBlocking line i.e error happening during MyClass.<init
I'm wondering if changing it to get() version will fix the issue happening during class  initialization.
    class MyClass @Inject constructor(
         private val a: SomeClassA,
         private val b: SomeClassB): ParentOfMyClass {
         override val propa : SomeClass = runBlocking {
              some code that takes time
          }
    }
}

Vs
class MyClass @Inject constructor(
         private val a: SomeClassA,
         private val b: SomeClassB): ParentOfMyClass {
         override val propa : SomeClass 
              get() = runBlocking {
                  some code that takes time
          }
    }
}


In principle yes, it will fix the issue but I am not sure if it would be faster to try it than asking here. .get() lazy-fies the variable and but also it makes it so it will get evaluated every time it is accessed so it might not be what you want.

What is the error message?
